# How to get continuous spectral data into intensities of channels centered around wavelengths?

Tags: spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, machine-learning

Currently, I am looking into using a spectral sensor from SparkFun in order to obtain spectroscopic data to feed into a trained neural network, however this sensor gives intensities based on inputs from channels centered around different wavelengths. The product can be seen here: https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14351

In order to generate the data to train our algorithm, we plan to take spectroscopic data of random samples of dirt and add traces of our target chemical's spectrum (i.e., add together and renormalize). What is a good way to get our continuous spectrum data into the format given by the sensor?

I was considering the using the Fourier transform on the continuous data and using the values located at the frequencies at which the channels are centered to "convert" the data to the proper format, but I'm not sure if this is physically correct. I know that $f=\frac{c}{\lambda}$, so maybe there needs to be a constant factor thrown in somewhere.

I'm not very well versed in chemistry, so I would appreciate some advice about this situation or more resources which could help enlighten me on this topic. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It isn't clear what you intend to use as input data. What is the source of the "*continuous*" data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the information in the link, the near-IR sensors can only give a response to channels: 610nm, 680nm, 730nm, 760nm, 810nm and 860nm, each with 20 nm FWHM. The sad news is that one cannot *extract more information from less*, not even by any fancy transform. The information is lost permanently because of a discontinuity of wavelengths. So, this data cannot generate a continuous spectrum of a sample all the wavelengths from 610 to 860 nm.

Perhaps all one can do is to look at the intensity patterns from the six channels and use that for training. Each channel output is a single number corresponding to the intensity to each nominal $\lambda$ with 20 nm bandwidth. So this sensor will generate six numbers for each analyzed sample. That is all. There is no way to interpolate in between the wavelengths, at least in NIR spectroscopy.

Comment: I was going to comment to the OP that there is no such thing as a continuous spectrum in practice. When they write "*I was considering the using the Fourier transform on the continuous data and using the values located at the frequencies at which the channels are centered to "convert" the data to the proper format*" what do they even mean by proper format?

Comment: @BuckThorn, My understanding is that the OP is thinking to collect the data at those six wavelengths ranging from 610 to 860 nm. He is wondering is there was a way to fill in the remaining wavelength info from this data so as to make a continuous spectrum. The answer is no.

Comment: (+1) And the original collected continuous spectra are apparently reflectance spectra, not absorbance or transmittance spectra. So each such spectrum would be processed to six average (over their respective 20 nm FWHM intervals) values for use as training data.

Answer (score 2):

My interpretation of the goal here is to take a "continuous" spectrum (or *high-resolution*) obtained with a good spectrometer and to convert that spectrum into a format comparable to that obtained with the SparkFun sensor.

The procedure of turning continuous data or rather, *discretely* sampled continuous data, into a new discrete spectrum with amplitudes at a new set of specific pre-selected frequencies is called re-sampling or binning, depending on the sampling rate of the input data.

If the input spectrum is oversampled, such that all of the desired frequencies are available at the same or comparable resolution, then it becomes a question of averaging over an appropriate interval (window) around each desired frequency. How to do this is not necessarily trivial (because the instrument has a filter of a particular shape over the window of each bin) but binning, meaning breaking up the original spectrum into bins and summing the contents of each bin, is one way to do this. Applying a polynomial interpolation function over each bin as a means of averaging (smoothing) is another. The results should be similar, the output for each bin (frequency) being a weighted average.

Here there is a registry issue in that neither resolution nor sampling rate match between the input and output. The easiest solution is to interpolate the input spectrum, applying appropriate smoothing (such as with a Savitsky-Golay interpolator) before resampling. Most numerical packages make this relatively easy to do. This is not a problem if the original "continuous" spectrum has high-resolution.

You also need to normalize the spectra somehow to compare them. If the input spectra vary in origin or how they were acquired or in the nature of the samples this might be an issue. IR spectral intensity, as I understand it, is proportional to concentration but peak intensities also depend on vibrational force constants which can vary between samples. I actually don't know what is the best way to do this part (re-normalization). It might involve some trial and error and visiting the literature.

Comment: I may not be looking hard enough, but I can’t find any procedures for spectral resampling online, only Iibraries. Am I on the right track in saying that I need to multiply by a Gaussian centered at the desired wavelength with the appropriate FWHM and then integrate over all wavelengths?

Comment: If you read my comment under your question and the first paragraph of my answer hopefully it is clear that it is not entirely clear what you want to do but I think I may have gotten it backwards. It sounds like you want to convert a low resolution "spectrum" (a set amplitudes at a small set of frequencies) and modify that so that you can add it to a higher resolution (complete) spectrum. Yes, one way to do this is to generate Gaussian (or whatever is an appropriate lineshape for IR spectroscopy) and add it to the high-res existing spectrum. I suspect however that ....

Comment: the limited data from the sparkfun sensor is leaving out a lot of information, so your "baked" spectrum will not provide a good representation of the actual high res spectrum that would be generated by the mixture.

Comment: Originally yeah, without the info I have now, I wanted to go from low to high res, but now it’s pretty clear that it’s more feasible to go from high to low res and train on the low res data

Comment: I guess what I’m asking for is clarification on what “averaging” over the appropriate interval, where the Gaussian approach I suggested is more like a weighted sum

Comment: Just to be clear then: you want to take a high-res spectrum and generate a set of values at selected frequencies that reflects the data obtained with the sparkfun sensor?

Comment: BTW what you wanted to do originally is actually not a (completely) terrible idea for some types of spectroscopy, specifically nmr. For instance, organic chemists typically report where a new compounds generates signal in the form of a short table. The same is possible with IR. But your data is not in this form. For any compound, the sensor is always sampling at a (too) small number of the same frequencies.

Comment: A final comment. It looks like Achem's answer addressed your original question. Therefore you may want to (1) edit your post to make that clear (2) accept his answer if indeed it addressed the question (3) post a new question with the new problem as you now see it. Finally, this might be a question for https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ There is something called the instrument filter function which seems relevant to what you are wondering.

Comment: There is also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ . That might actually be the best SE site for your question, since they may be able to tell you what the filter function for the sparkfun device is expected to (or does) look like.

Comment: Yes you got it exactly right; that's my new objective. Thank you for your help, I will try my luck with the resources you've referenced!